# I can not understand how to use OSM Bright without tiles host

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap

I have the following problem. I want to use osm bright, but I can’t understand how to do this. I found only how to use a standard OSM tiles skin:

```
https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png
```

Maybe you know a way how to connect the Bright version in the same way?

Comment: You probably want to either use a commercial tile provider such as https://cloud.maptiler.com/maps/bright/ , or deploy your own tile server.

Comment: Thanks for the help!